# How to use data by $http.get using a simple php api

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to connect my angularjs application to a simple php script which is simply returning a sql query from sqlite3 database.

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
try {
        $objDb = new PDO('sqlite:../dbase/shopper');
        $objDb -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "SELECT item.* ,
                        t.name AS type_name
                        FROM items item
                        INNER JOIN types t
                        ON t.id = item.type
                        ORDER BY item.date ASC";

        $result = $objDb->query($sql);

        if(!$result) {
                throw new  PDOException("The result returned no object");
        }
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $items = $result->fetchAll();

        $sql = "SELECT *
                        FROM types
                        ORDER BY id";
        $result = $objDb->query($sql);
        echo var_dump($result);
        if(!$result) {
                throw new  PDOException("The result returned no object");
        }
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $types = $result->fetchAll();

        echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => false,
                'items' => $items,
                'types' => $types
        ), JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS |JSON_HEX_QUOT |JSON_HEX_AMP );

} catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo json_encode(array(
                'error' => true,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ),JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS |JSON_HEX_QUOT |JSON_HEX_AMP );
}
```

When I check the php file address I can get the result :

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(41) " SELECT * FROM types ORDER BY id " }
{"error":false,"items":[{"id":"1","item":"Butter","qty":"1","type":"1","done":"0","date":"2014-10-06 02:45:51","type_name":"Qty"}],"types":[{"id":"1","name":"Qty"},{"id":"2","name":"Kg"}]}
```

If I use angularjs I get undefined results.

```
.controller('ShoppingListController', function($scope, $http, $log ){ 
    $scope.types = [];
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.item = '';
    $scope.qty = '';
    $scope.types = '';

     $scope.select = function( ) {

        $http({method: 'GET',url: 'mod/select.php'})
            .success(function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                    $scope.items = data.items;


                if(data.types) {

                    $scope.types = data.types;
                    $scope.type = $scope.types[0].id;

                }
            })
            .error(function(data,status,header){
                throw new Error('Something went wrong with selecting record');
            });
     };

     $scope.select();

});
```

console.log(data) shows :

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(41) " SELECT * 
            FROM types 
            ORDER BY id "
}
{"error":false,"items":[{"id":"1","item":"Butter","qty":"1","type":"1","done":"0","date":"2014-10-06 02:45:51","type_name":"Qty"}],"types":[{"id":"1","name":"Qty"},{"id":"2","name":"Kg"}]}
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Return a JSON response to the client and `console.log()` the data not the `$scope.items`

Comment: If you check the php link does not lines 40 -44 do that job ?

Comment: can you check the console.log(data) I have added to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must return a JSON response.  Fetch an associative array from your database and return this:

`echo json_encode($db_query);`

In Angular, you can then set the scope equal to the response ex:

`$scope.items = data.items;`

You can then access this in your view (be sure to have `ng-controller="ShoppingListController"`).

To iterate over the data:

`ng-repeat="item in items"`

You can then access each piece via `item.id` or whatever your key in the array may be.

Also, no need to set `$scope.items` at the top.

Edit:

```
.controller('ShoppingListController', function($scope, $http, $log) {
    function select() {
        $http.get('mod/select.php')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.items = data.items;

                if(data.types) {
                    $scope.types = data.types;
                    $scope.type = $scope.types[0].id;
                }
            });
    }

    select();

});
```

Comment: Noah , inside my question there is a php file pastebin link and yes I have those in my views and controllers. I can see the json also when I try php file and console.log data but I cant get for eg "data.items" or "data.type[0].id"

Comment: Since you're not calling the function in from the view, try my edit.

Comment: While you're at it, post your HTML augmented with Angular.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/fuCIxKvK8voXfHu0DuTy?p=info .. here it is except for php .. php is in the question

Comment: yes still I get undefined when I try console.log(data.items).. console.log(data) gives me my last edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62508/discussion-between-ytsejam-and-noah-matisoff).

Comment: I got to be up for work in 5 hours -- i'll check back on this then.  If it still hasn't been answered i'll help you work through it.

Comment: Get rid of the Object PDO statement from your response.

Comment: echo var_dump($result); this was making the problem yes you are right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `var_dump();` And BTW you don't need to echo with `var_dump()`, it already appends to the output buffer. The `var_dump()` makes your response invalid JSON.